# SwiftUI: Shuffling answers in multiple choice quiz only when loading a new question

Tags: swiftui, shuffle

I want to shuffle answer options from Trivia API only when loading a new question, not every time a user selects an answer. Currently, the answers shuffle each time a user makes a selection.

For example, when question a is loaded, maybe like this:

> "Who won the 2014 World Cup in Brazil?"

I have 4 different answer options (buttons), maybe like this:

> "Russia", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy"

When I chooses an answer by pressing one of the buttons I can see how my buttons shuffle again before I go to the next question. So it will maybe look like this after I've pressed a button in the example:

> "Italy", "Spain", "Russia", "Germany".

Note that I have a button with the text "Next" that user can only can press after an answer has been chosen.

I have attempted to shuffle answer options by using a `shuffleAnswers()` function inside my ForEach loop. My expectation was that this would shuffle the answer options for that specific question. However, the current implementation shuffles the answers every time a user selects an answer, which is not the desired behavior.

Here is my code for my `shuffleAnswers()` function:

```
func shuffleAnswers() -> [String] {
        var answers = api.QnAData[currentQuestionIndex].incorrectAnswers
        answers.append(api.QnAData[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswer)
        answers = answers.compactMap { $0.removingPercentEncoding }
        return answers.shuffled()
    }
```

And here is my code for my ForEach loop:

```
 if !api.QnAData.isEmpty {
            ForEach(shuffleAnswers(), id: \.self) { shuffledAnswer in
                    Button(action: {
                        if answerSelected == nil {
                            if let decodedAnswer = shuffledAnswer.removingPercentEncoding {
                                answerSelected = decodedAnswer.removingPercentEncoding
                                hasUserAnswered = true
                            
                            }
                            if shuffledAnswer.removingPercentEncoding == api.QnAData[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswer.removingPercentEncoding {
                                
                                answerSelected = shuffledAnswer.removingPercentEncoding
                                
                                
                                if let userAnswer = answerSelected?.removingPercentEncoding {
                                    if userAnswer == api.QnAData[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswer.removingPercentEncoding {
                                        score += 1
                                        print("Correct answer, your score: \(score)")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Wrong answer, your score: \(score)")
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                print("wrong answer, player score: \(score)")
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        
                        Text(shuffledAnswer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `shuffleAnswers()` returns shuffled array every time you access it.

Try to cache it somehow to prevent this. For example, you can make an state and only shuffle `onAppear` (as you asked):

```
@Stated cachedShuffledAnswers = [String]()

var body: some View {
    ,,,
    .onAppear {
        self.cachedShuffledAnswers = shuffleAnswers()
    }
}
```

Then use the cached version in the `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(cachedShuffledAnswers, id: \.self) ...
```

<sub>Note that this is just a preview to a possibility and I recommend you to try decouple the logic from the UI soon in the future</sub>

Comment: Excuse me but where in my code should I write this code: .onAppear {
        self.cachedShuffledAnswers = shuffleAnswers()
    } ? @Mojtaba Hosseini

Comment: It's a view modifier and can be applied on one of the views. for example the list. Try to apply it in the `ForEach {...}` after the close braces.

Comment: I get this error then, "index out of range"

Comment: From your previous question, you are doing some async function call in your `.task{...}` where you set the `api.QnAData`.
Move the code `cachedShuffledAnswers = shuffleAnswers()` to the `.task{...}` just after you call the `try await api.getQnAData(...)`.
So you get the  index out of range error, because the `.onAppear{...}` is done before you have finished setting `api.QnAData` in your `.task{...}`.
In any case, you should use `if currentQuestionIndex < api.QnAData.count {...}` to avoid the index out of range in your `func shuffleAnswers(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me solve my problems.